# Debug old Android version with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I develop with Android version 23. But now I like to debug a device having only version 19 installed.

To do it I changed my gradle file to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['dtp_library'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':libs:dtp_library')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'        
}
```

But this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:19.+'
```

throws the compiler error

> Failed to resolve 'com.android.support:design:19.+'

How to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure there is a API 19 appcompat/design/support/ libraries? Appcompat was only added in API 21, so having `19+` doesn't make sense

Comment: you can debug your app on all devices in range [minSdkVersion .. targetSdkVersion] without changing the target sdk version. Just create emulator with sdk 17, or connect your old device and turn debug mode there

Comment: read about support library, you don't understand its purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample of my build.gradle and it runs absolutely fine on an API 19 device.

Few things to note are that you don't need to decrement the compile SDK. This is like having Java 8 installed, but compiling Java 6 code. It still works.

Also, I think the `appcompat-v7` library depends on the `support-v4` library, so you don't need to include that.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidstack.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the key is "you don't need to decrement the compile SDK"... helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `compile 'com.android.support:design:19.+'` then try